# Summary of multiple factored columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am trying to summarise multiple columns of a dataframe that each contain data with the same levels into an easier format to work with.

I begin with a dataframe similar to the one below, in which various people have registered their satisfaction with a number of aspects of their lives:

```
person=as.factor(c("Jack","Jack","John","Jill"))
job=as.factor(c("happy","sad","very happy","sad"))
home=as.factor(c("happy","sad","very happy","happy"))
car=as.factor(c("happy","sad","sad","happy"))

df<-data.frame(person,job,home,car)
```

[image]

I wish to transform this to instead appear in the below format:

[image]

I believe that this will be easier to work with in R going forward, and for other users in excel.

I have tried to melt/cast the data and to use the table() and count() functions but I am unable to achieve the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It feels like a dupe, but here's an attempt using `reshape2::recast` which is just a `melt/dcast` wrapper

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df, variable ~ value, id.var = 1L)
# Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
#   variable happy sad very happy
# 1      job     1   2          1
# 2     home     2   1          1
# 3      car     2   2          0
```

Or if the data is very big, we could implement `data.table` equivalent too

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df), 1L), variable ~ value)
# Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
#    variable happy sad very happy
# 1:      job     1   2          1
# 2:     home     2   1          1
# 3:      car     2   2          0
```

In both methods you can specify `fun.aggregate =` for different aggregation functions.

Comment: Thank you - this answers the question exactly.